# Database / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

boa tarde, estou tentando criar um produto em relação à sua etiqueta identificada, por exemplo, quando envio o form uma linha nula é criada no banco de dados.

```
public function store(Produto $produto, Request $request)
{

    $data = $this->requestValidate();


    $produto->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $produto->save();
    $produto->tags()->attach(request('tags'));

    if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->image->isValid()) {
        $name = uniqid(date('HisYmd'));
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $nameFile = "{$name}.{$extension}";
        $imagePath = $request->image->storeAs('img_produtos', $nameFile, 'img_produtos');
        $data['image'] = $imagePath;
    }



    Produto::create($data);
    return redirect(route('user.profile'));
}
```

aqui está como ele aparece no banco de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar? Sou iniciante no Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

O teu primeiro código

```
$produto->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$produto->save();
```

é o responsavel, ele vai criar um registo na base de dados e inserir só o id do usúario.